# copy header in each cell of its row

Tags: text-processing

I have a file:

```
AC  AF  AN
3   0.375   8
3   0.375   8
```

I want the output as:

```
AC  AF  AN
AC=3    AF=0.375    AN=8
AC=3    AF=0.375    AN=8
```

Is there any unix command for that?

Comment: Is it really just `AC`, `AF` and `AN`? Or do you want a solution which works for more than three columns?

Comment: Where is the extra row coming from?

Comment: @Mekeor, that works for more than three columns

Comment: @steeldriver, ignore that extra row, its my typo error,

Comment: removed the extra row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk '
  NR==1 {split($0,a); $1=$1} 
  NR>1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=a[i]"="$i} 
  1' OFS='\t' yourfile
```

Explanation:

- split the first record (header row) into an array, based on the default field separator; reassign `$1` so that the record gets written with the new output field separator
- for the remaining records, loop over fields prepending each field value with the array element corresponding to the field index, separated by `=`
- print records with tab as the output field separator

Comment: nice that it works and solves OPs issue but without explanation it's not so much instructive, is it?

Comment: @MekeorMelire I have added a brief explanation

Answer (score 3):

```
< yourfile \
   perl -pale '
      $. == 1 and push(@A,@F),next;
      $_ = join $", map { "$A[$_]=$F[$_]" } 0..$#F;
   ' |
 column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        header[i] = $i
        printf "%s\t", $i
    }
    print ""
}

NR > 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        printf "%s=%s\t", header[i], $i
    }
    print ""
}
```

1. create  a file named **awkprog** and paste the above contents into it. 
2. assuming your file name to be **data.txt**. 
3. Then, run **awk -f awkprog data.txt**